# What does 'continuous' mean for PouchDB replicate()?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

According to the PouchDB replicate() [documentation](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#replicate_a_database) it's possible to add a `continuous` option to `Pouch.replicate()`:

> If true starts subscribing to changes in the first database and replicating them to the second.

I understand what this means, but how does it work?  I've looked at the code, but it's hard to understand how 'subscribing' is accomplished.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what the first database is.

If it is a remote CouchDB, pouch makes an `xhr` request to the `db/_changes` resource for that couchdb (http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_database_API#Changes). It does indeed set [feed=longpoll](https://github.com/daleharvey/pouchdb/blob/master/src/adapters/pouch.http.js#L659), as Kim mentioned. The `longpoll` option makes couch wait until there is a change before it sends anything- this way you don't poll over an over only to find there were no changes.

If the first database is a local PouchDB, it listens for "change" events, which are triggered whenever a change is made in the database.

Either way, when the replicator sees a change come in, it replicates it to the second database.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the PouchDB code, but the only way to do that is to listen to the [`_changes` feed](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_database_API#Changes), probably with `feed` set to `long-polling` or `continuous`.